# @OneToOne Uni directional with cascading didn’t delete by sql query

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa, one-to-one

I tried to create two table (primary and secondary)
 with @OneOnOne relation.(I’m using Postgres )

I define the primery table like this:

```
Class Table1{
@GeneratedValue
@Id
@Column
private int Id;

@OneToOne(cascade =CasscadeType.ALL)
public Table2 table2;
```

My problem is when I try to delete the table by sql query (delete from Table1) the data delete from Table1 but it didn’t delete row from table2 which related to Table1

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)